# Empty Front Page With Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Ultimately, the Empty Front Page module has got it to look exactly like I want it.  However, this causes Google Analytics code to not show up on the front page.

I try adding a new Basic Page content, but it forces me to give it a name which shows up when I publish, also, I think my theme is also adding a button to the bottom of this page as well, and I also get an RSS icon in the lower left corner.

I've installed Empty Page and Front Page modules, but I do not know how to work them, there are no settings associated with those modules and I also can't seem to find anywhere in Drupal where to get this to work the way I want.

I'd also like to stay away from PHP code as when upgrades come in, I don't want to have to have to update that code every time as well.

Comment: Manually put the Google Analytics code in your html.tpl.php file between `<script></script>` tags.

Comment: "I'd also like to stay away from PHP code as when upgrades come in, I don't want to have to have to update that code every time as well."